# Proper choice for a database consisting of a dictionary

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary, shelve

I have a large dictionary that has the following format:

```
dict["randomKey"]=[dict1,dict2,int,string]
```

There will probably be some tens of thousands of keys. `dict1` itself has ~ 100 keys.

***Question is***: I need this dictionary to be stored on a server and read by multiple machines. What is the best format for this?

I am now using `shelve` which is very easy to use. 
However, I will be needing to get all the keys from the main dictionary(dict) for a certain value of a key from `dict1` or `dict2`, which is taking some time and I'm afraid that when the dictionary will be much larger, as in 50k keys, it's going to take forever.
I've read about `sqlite3` and it seems a good alternative but I don't know if it's a good solution for my needs.

I don't really need the database to be accessible to other than Python programs (it would be nice though) but I need it to be fast,stable and to be able to have many computers read from it in the same time. Thanks!

Comment: A document DB might be better suited for your needs compared to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd choose a database with native json support, which can search in json dictionaries efficiently. I like PostgreSQL:

A table for your data:

```
create table dict (
  key text primary key,
  dict1 jsonb not null default '{}',
  dict2 jsonb not null default '{}',
  intval integer not null,
  strval text not null
);
```

Fill it up with some sample values:

```
insert into dict
select
  i::text,
  (select
    jsonb_object(
      array_agg('k'||v::text),
      array_agg('v'||(v+i)::text)
    ) from generate_series(1,1000) as v
  ),
  (select
    jsonb_object(
      array_agg('k'||v::text),
      array_agg('v'||(v+i)::text)
    ) from generate_series(1,1000) as v
  ),
  i,
  i::text
from generate_series(1,10000) as i;
```

Get the key for which there's value `v134` for key `k6` in `dict1`:

```
select key from dict where dict1 @> '{"k6":"v134"}';
 key 
-----
 128
(1 row)

Time: 232.843 ms
```

You can even index the dictionary columns for even faster search if your table is really large. But these indexes would be larger than a table itself and the database can decide that it's safer to not use them anyway:

```
create index dict_dict1_idx on dict using gin(dict1);
create index dict_dict2_idx on dict using gin(dict2);
```

You can force the database to use the indexes, if you know that it's beneficial:

```
set enable_seqscan=off;
select key from dict where dict1 @> '{"k6":"v134"}';
 key 
-----
 128
(1 row)

Time: 8.955 ms
```

Comment: i've done some research but i can't really tell... From your experience, is there a significant difference between sqlite and postgresql? thx for the answer

Comment: I'd say that they're as similar as a kick scooter is to an 18-wheeler truck.